# Excel HLOOKUP to reference multiple Cells as "lookup_value"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

In this file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rwPyt7RKLCVIMWEuAxdl3H3vYxXtUX8S

Cell A3 on the first sheet "Import Template" has this formula:

`=IFERROR(IF(HLOOKUP(A$2,Sheet1!$A:$ZZ,ROW(A2),FALSE)="","",HLOOKUP(A$2,Sheet1!$A:$ZZ,ROW(A2),FALSE)),"")`

Which automatically brings over values from "Sheet1" if they match on the column header

(Super User helped me find that formula here: [Map/Copy values from one sheet to another in excel if they match on column header](https://superuser.com/questions/1410018/map-copy-values-from-one-sheet-to-another-in-excel-if-they-match-on-column-heade/1410052#1410052))

It works well for one template that we use, which has the full set of headers in Row 1

However you'll see in the linked file that there are two "Header" rows, where the first row is a specifier for what type of header the second row is, namely the Addresses of 1, 2, and Company

Since the headers for all 3 addresses are "Street", "City", "State/Province", and "Postal Code", the formula is bringing over only the first occurrences of matches to those headers that it finds, for all three addresses

Is there any way to use Hlookup's "lookup-value" to say "I need first occurrence of Street, City, State/Province, and Postal Code" and then later in another cell "I need the second occurrence", and so forth?

Or is there maybe another function that could be used instead of/in conjunction with HLOOKUP to do this?

Or will I just have to manually copy over Address 2 and Company Address if the source has it?

Another alternative I could do is temporarily change that second row to "Street 1", "City 1", etc. and then remove it when it's time to actually upload the file, but I'd like to have something I don't have to remember something manual like that for, if possible.

Data from First sheet:

Row 1:
                                                                    ADDRESS 1
ADDRESS 2                   COMPANY ADDRESS                         Key Dates       STATUS GROUP    System Tags (Select Y if applies)                                                       User Tags   Notes               SOCIAL MEDIA

Row 2: 
First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Prefix  Suffix  Full Legal Name About   Country Code    Mobile Phone    Country Code    Home Phone  Country Code    Work Phone  Country Code    Other  Phone    Email   Email 2 Street  City    State/Province  Postal Code Street  City    State/Province  Postal Code Company Street  City    State/Province  Postal Code Country / Region    Title   Department  Birthday    Home Anniversary    "Required*
Captured/
Connected"  Agent   Vendor  Investor    Loan Officer    Talent  Builder REO Short Sale  Expired FSBO    Sphere  Allied Resource Referral Sources    First Time Buyer    Tags    Notes   Source  Other Source    Added   Facebook    Twitter Linkedin    Google+ Pinterest   Instagram   Houzz

Row 3:
Dyan        Dannheisser                             7539518462                  dyan@mail.com       123 E Main St   Miami, Florida          123 E Main St   Miami, Florida              123 E Main St   Miami, Florida              office manager                                                                          Google,Gmail

Row 4: 
Elsbeth J.  Crusius                             4567893210                  elsbeth@something.com       456 S Main St   Hackensack, New Jersey          456 S Main St   Hackensack, New Jersey              456 S Main St   Hackensack, New Jersey              Attorney                                                                            Google,Gmail

Data from "Sheet1"

Row 1:
First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Suffix  Birthday    About   Tags    Email   Email 2 Mobile Phone    Home Phone  Street  City    State/Province  Postal Code Street  City    State/Province  Postal Code Company Title

Row 2:
Dyan        Dannheisser             Google,Gmail    dyan@mail.com       3216549870  7539518462  123 E Main St   Miami, Florida          555 Any Road    Miami ::: Miami FL ::: FL   33176 ::: 33176     office manager

Row 3:
Elsbeth J.  Crusius             Google,Gmail    elsbeth@something.com       123-456-7891    4567893210  456 S Main St   Hackensack, New Jersey          555 Some Other Road Hackensack  New Jersey  7601        Attorney

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1412185/edit) to include sample data? not everyone wants to or is able to download random files online and your question will lose its value once the linked file is not available anymore

Comment: How about SUMPRODUCT function?

Comment: I'm actually looking for something that would essentially concatenate the two cells into the "lookup_value" variable of hlookup, not trying to multiply two numeric values